# php isset not working properly echo back empty

Tags: php

in my code when i click on submit 3 btn it echos back empty $email though post is created in db the title is always empty, however if i change `if(isset($_POST['submit3']))` to `if(isset($_POST['submit1']))`, it doesn't enter the details into db or echo back anything

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    $("#form1").show();
    $("#form2").hide();
    $("#form3").hide();    


 $('button[name="submit1"]').click(function(e) {
    $("#form2").show();
    $("#form1").hide();  
     $("#form3").hide();   
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('button[name="submit2"]').click(function(e) {
    $("#form3").show();
    $("#form1").hide();
    $("#form2").hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
  </script>
<body>
<form id="form1" method="post" >     

            <div>
                <input type="text" id="inputemail" name="email" placeholder="Email" height="34px" >
            </div>  
            <div >
                <button id="submit1" type="submit" name="submit1" ><strong>Start</strong></button>
            </div>      
 </form> 

<form id="form2" method="post" style="display:none">         

            <div>
                <input type="text" id="inputpwd" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" height="34px" required>
            </div>
            <div >
                    <button id="submit2" type="submit" name="submit2" ><strong>Next</strong></button>
            </div> 

 </form>  

<form id="form3" method="post" style="display:none"> 
        <div required>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="book_type[]"> Romance</input><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="book_type[]"> Action</input><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="book_type[]"> suspense</input><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="book_type[]"> thriller</input><br>
                </div>
                <div >
                    <button id="submit3" type="submit" name="submit3" onclick="submitform();"><strong>Next</strong></button>
                </div> 
</form>
</body>
<?php
$email=$_POST['email'];
$pwd=$_POST['pwd'];
$bookchk=array(); 
$todaydate = new DateTime();
$todaydate =$todaydate->format('Y-m-d H-i-s');

if(isset($_POST['submit3']))
{
echo $email;
$formarg= array('post_type'=>'details',
                        'post_title'=>$email,
            'post_author'=>'1',
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'post_date'=>$todaydate );
    $wpdb->insert('wp_posts',$formarg); 
    $bookpostid=$wpdb->insert_id;
    foreach($_POST['book_type'] as $selectedplan)
        {       
        $bookchk[]=$selectedplan;       
        }

    update_field('field_561b9999ebb56',$bookchk[0],$contestpostid); 
    update_field('pwd',$pwd,$bookpostid);
}
?>
```

Comment: You're using 3 separate forms. Only one is submited.

Comment: I would output `$_POST` like: `var_dump($_POST);` to see what values you are getting and test from there

Comment: seems you have not a proper click function for button[name="submit"] or  at least I do not see it your javascript code

Comment: with var dump i get array (size=2)
  'book_type' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '0' (length=1)
  'submit3' => string 'Next' (length=4)

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
<button id="submit3" type="submit" name="submit3" value="Next" onclick="submitform();"><strong>Next</strong></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['email'])){$_SESSION["email"] = $_POST['email'];}
if(isset($_POST['pwd'])){$_SESSION["pwd"] = $_POST['pwd'];}
if(isset($_POST['book_type'])){$_SESSION["book_type"] = $_POST['book_type'];}

if(isset($_SESSION["email"]) && isset($_SESSION["pwd"]) && isset($_SESSION["book_type"])){

  echo "email:".$_SESSION["email"]."<br>";
  echo "pwd:" .$_SESSION["pwd"]."<br>";

  echo("options:");

  for($i=0;$i<sizeof($_SESSION["book_type"]);$i++){

    echo $_SESSION["book_type"][$i]."|";
  }

  session_destroy();
  $_SESSION["email"] = "";
  $_SESSION["pwd"] = "";
  $_SESSION["book_type"] = "";
}

$todaydate = new DateTime();
$todaydate =$todaydate->format('Y-m-d H-i-s');

?>
<body>

<?php if(empty($_SESSION["email"])):?>
<form id="form1" method="post">     

            <div>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" height="34px" >
            </div>  
            <div >
                <input id="submit1" type="submit" name="submit1" value = "Start">
            </div>      
 </form> 
<?php endif;?>

<?php if(isset($_SESSION["email"]) && empty($_SESSION["pwd"]) ):?>
<form id="form2" method="post">         

            <div>
                <input type="text" id="pwd" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" height="34px" required>
            </div>
            <div >
                    <input id="submit2" type="submit" name="submit2" value = "Next">
            </div> 

 </form>  
<?php endif;?>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["email"]) && isset($_SESSION["pwd"]) && empty($_SESSION["book_type"])):?>
<form id="form3" method="post"> 
        <div required>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="book_type[]"> Romance</input><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="book_type[]"> Action</input><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="book_type[]"> suspense</input><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="book_type[]"> thriller</input><br>
                </div>
                <div >
                    <button id="submit3" type="submit" name="submit3" onclick="submitform();"><strong>Next</strong></button>
                </div> 
</form>
<?php endif;?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

- You are getting back empty `$email` when submitting through `button
  id="submit3"` because an input field with attribute `name="email"`
  doesn't exists within your third form `<form id="form3" ...> </form>`
- You are receving nothing when submitting through `button
  id="submit1"` because `e.preventDefault();` method prevents form from
  submitting when you click submit button.

To proceed submitting of your first and second form remove `e.preventDefault();` from submit button click handlers